# How to force program to use Java 7

Tags: java

I am running 64 bit Windows 7, Java 8. I need one of my programs to run Java 7 for a test. If possible, I would like only that program to run Java 7.

Comment: If you're executing it with the `java` command, you can use the path to `java.exe` in your Java 7 folder to specify which version to run.

Comment: Change your java home and make sure java home is in path.

Comment: What format is your program? An executable .jar? A class file? How are you running it?

Comment: do you have java 7 installed?

Comment: Are you using an IDE? Alternately, you can just open it with what ever version you select if you right click on the jar -> open with -> browse etc.